# How to connect react component in react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created modal in react native. I have added filter option icon in top right corner now when the user clicks on it should open the modal. How can I do that ? I have added Options icon in navigation.js but now how to connect it with modal component ?

In code below `setModalVisible` is available in filteroptions.js and not in navigation.js

Code:

navigation.js:

```
Updates: {
            screen: UpdatesScreen,

            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                headerTitle: 'Myapp',
                headerRight:<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true);}}>
                                <MenuIcon style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 15}} name="md-options" size={25} color="white"/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>,

            })
        },
```

filteroptions.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View, Alert} from 'react-native';

export default class FilteroptionsModel extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When user clicks on filter button in top right corner (see screenshot) he should  be able to see the box modal on screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a modal you don't necessarily need to add it to the navigation. You can just include it in your page and initially have it be invisible, then when the user clicks your button you can make the modal visible. But if you want to add it to the navigation why not just add like any other component. However, adding it to the navigation will take you to another page when you navigate to the component. Of course you can add a nested navigator to work around that, but I think it adds unnecessary complexity.

**Update**
You will first declare a `Header` component.

```
export default class MyHeader extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    <View>
      <View>...Your left Icon here</View>
      <View>...Your Title here</View>
      <View>...Your right Icon Here</View>
    </View>
  }
}
```

Then in your page you will render this component first, pass as props your handlers and then render the rest of the page.

```
export default class MyPage extends React.PureComponent {

  yourRigthHandler = () => {
     this.setState({modaVisible: true});
  }

  yourLeftHandler = () => {....}

  render() {
    <View>
      <MyHeader 
         LeftHandler={yourLeftHandler}
         LeftHandler={yourRigthHandler}>
           ....
      </MyHeader>
    </View>
  }
}
```

inside the handlers you can call the navigation functions to navigate to another page or change the components state to make the moda visible.The handlers will be passed as props to your header and you will add them as `onPress` handlers to your buttons.

Comment: But I have added icon in navigation.js i.e `headerRight: Icon` now onclick the box modal should open up how can I do that ? box modal is inside another file. So I cannot implement box modal in navigation.js So how should I connect it ?

Comment: Since the button is in the navigator you need to add a handler for when the user clicks the button to inform you modal to turn visible. They cannot directly communicate so through I suppose you can do it through your global state. While it could work I don't think it is the best solution. This https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/707#issuecomment-299859578 offers a different approach.

Comment: So you are saying I should create separate screen for box modal and then I have to connect it using stacknavigator is it correct ?

Comment: This is the option suggested on GitHub. But what I would do is to have the modal turn visible/invisible when the user presses the button on the navigator.

Comment: Then if I follow your approach then how will I add that icon in header navigation ? Is it possible to add connect icon and modal from two different files ?

Comment: If they are in different files you cannot access the state of one from the other. You will need to use some sort of global state to do it, which is not really the correct approach. If you don't want to use the global state for that you can create a custom header instead of using the navigator's header, that way you can pass your callback and change the components state.

Comment: Can you add that in your answer I couldn't get how to implement this -> `you can create a custom header instead of using the navigator's header, that way you can pass your callback and change the components state`